# Using AES256 to verify data authenticity

Tags: security, encryption, aes

Assume the following scenario:

- I have two different servers, A and B.
- Server A hosts a static file, representing a set of valid identifiers. Let's say those are represented as integers. The set is rather large; assume it contains around 30-50% of all 4 byte integers. The contents of this file never changes.
- Clients can download this set from server A. Clients must be able to transparently see the actual int values returned by A.
- Clients can then invoke some API function on server B, passing in some of those identifiers (int values) to server B
- Server B must verify that the passed-in integer is "valid", meaning it is indeed part of the set of integers hosted on server A
- Server B has no ongoing access to server A, and it has no knowledge of the static data file

Is there a secure way for server B to verify the parameter passed in from the client?

My idea so far would be:

- Server A exposes the numbers, as well as an encrypted version of the number (encrypted with, say, AES256)
- The key used for encryption is shared between server A and server B
- Clients can call host B using the encrypted number
- Host B can decrypt this and therefore verify the number originates from host A, and thereby must have been part of the set of numbers

Would this approach be secure?

Given the exposed set of integers covers a large fraction of all possible integer values, and clients can see the encrypted version of each of those - does that open up any way to reverse engineer the encryption key? Or suffer from any other security flaws?

---

Why am I thinking of doing something dodgy like this at all? In short, cost reduction.

I'm exposing a very large, chunked dataset that clients can download in parts (or - in case of any malicious actors - in full). They need to be able to invoke a server API requesting do invoke certain actions based on this data. The server needs to ensure the input data is valid.

The natural approach of course would be for the host to load up the data from internal sources to verify. Since this is all going to be hosted on AWS serverless, that would mean extra cost for each request though (reading a file, or reading a DB, etc. - all charged separately), which I'd ideally like to avoid. If I could trust the data passed in by the client, I might be able to dodge some costs and cut a little latency while at it.

Comment: The first step should be to define what you want to achieve (define your security requirements). Designing an algorithm is step two. Based on your question you skipped step 1 so your question "is this secure" can not be answered because it is not clear what security requirements have to be fullfilled.

Comment: @Robert I'm indeed no security export, so maybe this is too native, but: The goal is simply for server B to verify whether a number passed in by a client is contained in the set of numbers hosted on server A, without direct connectivity to A (aside from initially sharing keys between A and B). I don't need banking transaction-level 100% security, if someone after manages to submit 1 fake number every other year that's fine - just don't want someone being able to consistently and frequently do this (by reversing keys or any other means)

Comment: Any why do you want to use AES256? This scenario screams out loud "use public cryptography": generate a key pair on server A, get the public key of that keypair onto server B in a secure way and then let Server A give away signed "numbers" (I would call them tokens"). Server B can verify the tokens and problem solved.

Comment: @Robert That sounds very sensible! That actually makes things a little easier for me yet - thanks!